# Data storage query in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi

I have connected power bi desktop to Azure table storage and have built report and have published it to Power Bi service. I would like to know where my data is stored. is it stored in my Power Bi desktop or is it in cloud and just a connection has been made to the azure tabular storage.

if there is just a connection with tabular storage why my pbix file increases in size when data in the tabular storage increases.
note: in Azure Tabular storage, you don't get option for direct query or import.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the old IDEA (And I don't find any update)

https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=98a21b8d-e4a4-4247-b6e3-78beb1b3b436

Actually, it is not supported to connect to Azure Table Storage in power bi by a direct query. Then we have import